# Where can I find the House of Representatives and the Senate's journals?

Tags: united-states, congress

Where can I find the House of Representatives and the Senate's journals that the Constitution requires they keep of the what is said and what votes take place? The GPO provides the Congressional Record, but the chambers must keep their own journals of everything that is said, so is this published on the Internet? If so, where?

Comment: I'd dispute that the Constitution requires they keep a record of "what is said". Article I, Section 5 requires that "Each House shall keep a journal of its proceedings", but that's not synonymous with keeping a record of their debates (indeed, the Congressional Record describes itself as "Proceedings and Debates of the [nth] Congress" which would support the notion that "proceedings" and "debates" are two separate things.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

https://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/browse/collection.action?collectionCode=CREC

-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=